# Missing icons in GNOME when installing another app instance (through another distribution channel -Ubuntu 22.04-)

Tags: 22.04, icons, gnome-shell

This did not happen when running 23.10, but with LTS, whenever I install an app, then again from another source, the second instance of its icon does not show up in GNOME launcher or search box. For example, when installing a Snap through the App Store, then the same app from Flathub, or as an AppImage or downloading the .deb package.
Thanks in advance.